# Asterisk doesn't start properly at system startup. DNS lookup fails

Tags: asterisk

When I start my Ubuntu system it attempts two DNS lookups. One to find out what my internet-routers external ip is. And one to find the IP of my PSTN-SIP-provider.

Both fails.

```
[Apr  7 22:14:54] WARNING[1675] chan_sip.c: Invalid address for externhost keyword: sip.mydomain.com   
...   
[Apr  7 22:14:54] WARNING[1675] acl.c: Unable to lookup 'sip.myprovider.com'
```

And since the DNS fails it cannot register properly a cannot make outgoing or incoming calls.

If I later, after bootup, restart asterisk everything works excelent.

Any idea how I should setup things so that either:

1. Delay Asterisk startup so that DNS is up and healthy first.
2. Somehow get Asterisk to re-try the DNS thing later.

Regards
Leif

Comment: Do you have static IP or DHCP?

Comment: The external IP of my system is DHCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing the start-order in /etc/rc*.d to get the DNS to start before asterisk.
However, following system updates had the tendency to push back the original start order. (At least I think so. I fixed it, it worked for a week, then stopped again.)

Since I upgraded the system to Ubuntu 10.04 it just works.